# Get and concatenate all the selected item in CheckedBoxComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm having a problem when I select more than 1 in my `CheckedBoxComboBox`.

I can do this using a `CheckListBox` using this code.

```
objNPTBEL.workdayidlist = null;
for (int x = 0; x < checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count; x++)
{
     if (x < checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count - 1)
         objNPTBEL.workdayidlist += checkedListBox1.GetItemText(checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[x]) + ",";
     else
         objNPTBEL.workdayidlist += checkedListBox1.GetItemText(checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[x]);
}
```

> Ex. Output, "415073,415072"

But I want a `ComboBox UI`. I found this custom tool `CheckBoxComboBox`.

[CheckBox ComboBox Extending the ComboBox Class and Its Items](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21085/CheckBox-ComboBox-Extending-the-ComboBox-Class-and)

And this is my current code to get all the selected items in `CheckedBoxComboBox`.

```
int x = 0;
objNPTBEL.workdayidlist = null;
for (int i = 0; i < checkBoxComboBox1.CheckBoxItems.Count; i++)
{
     if (checkBoxComboBox1.CheckBoxItems[i].CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
     {
         x = x + 1;
         for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)
         {
              if (j < x - 1)
              {
                  objNPTBEL.workdayidlist += checkBoxComboBox1.GetItemText(checkBoxComboBox1.CheckBoxItems[i].Text) + ",";
              }
              else
              {
                  objNPTBEL.workdayidlist += checkBoxComboBox1.GetItemText(checkBoxComboBox1.CheckBoxItems[i].Text);
              }
          }
      }
}
```

When I select more than 1 item my output looks like this.

> ex. Output 415073415072,415072

Comment: You don't need the inner for loop... you should just do `objNPTBEL.workdayidlist += checkBoxComboBox1.CheckBoxItems[i].Text + ",";` in `if` block and then Trim the last comma after the for loop...

Comment: Thank you @Chetan, I've removed the inner for loop and it's working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't get too complex, just add the comma every time then trim it off at the end..

I can't work out why there is an inner for loop, but I've left it alone because you know your project better than me. It will cause duplicate items in the output but you haven't indicated that that is a problem - I'm only solving the problem that the numbers are run together without a comma. If you don't want duplicate items too, you can remove the inner for loop also - basically just do it like you had first time but with an `if` that looks to see if the item is checked

```
     for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)
     {
         objNPTBEL.workdayidlist += checkBoxComboBox1.GetItemText(checkBoxComboBox1.CheckBoxItems[i].Text) + ","; 
     }

...

objNPTBEL.workdayidlist = objNPTBEL.workdayidlist.TrimEnd(',');
```

Probably worth pointing out that it may be more useful to make `objNPTBEL.workdayidlist` something like a `List<int>`  rather than a csv